# how to set % wildacards at the beginning of a wmic inside a for in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, wmic

I'm getting a weird behaviour calling wmic inside a batch file,  im trying to get the id of a process but when i set %% at the beginning of the string in the like command, it returns random numbers, but when i use them at the end its behaviour is normal

i have tried %%, %, ^%, \% and none of them works. all i have read indicates that i need to escape the % using a %% but i can't make it work at the start of the string

```
    @echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    FOR /F %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:c omcp_*.log') do set "FILENAME=%%i"
    FOR /F "usebackq" %%A IN ('%FILENAME%') DO set "SIZE=%%~zA"
    set commie=0
    IF DEFINED LASTFILENAME (
        IF "%FILENAME%" == "%LASTFILENAME%" (
            if DEFINED LASTSIZE (
                IF "%SIZE%"=="%LASTSIZE%" ( 
->->->                        for /f "UseBackQ tokens=2 delims==" %%f in (`wmic PROCESS WHERE "COMMANDLINE LIKE '%%winlog%%'" GET ProcessID /value ^| find "="`) do set "commie=%%f"
                    echo !commie!
                    IF !commie! equ 0 echo "subir monitor"
                    ) else ( 
                        echo "re subir monitor" 
                )
            )
        )
    )

    set LASTFILENAME=%FILENAME%
    set LASTSIZE=%SIZE%

    REM setx LASTFILENAME FILENAME
    REM setx LASTSIZE SIZE
```

when i use only the last %% it work and return the id of the winlogon process, and that should happen if i use the start %%, the actual output is random, at least i think are random, numbers; for example:8260,11576,8596 and this is independent of the value that is searched

Comment: I don't get the question, which variables and wildcards are you refering to?

Comment: in the wmic calling, in the like part, i cant make the first 2 %% of the winlog word to work as sjpud

Comment: **Your script is not correct**, there is one opening parenthesis missing, _(on line `12`)_, and one line with a closing parenthesis missing, _(it should be line `15`)_. Please also be aware that you're asking for help with code despite not providing us with the known or possible values of `%LASTFILENAME%` and `%LASTSIZE%`, or what exactly you are expecting the content of `COMMANDLINE` to contain.

Comment: I'd suggest that you redirect your `wmic` output to a file and then examine that file carefully using a hex-editor. IIRC, the format of `wmic` is not as-expected.

Comment: for completion sake, the idea of the batch file is to check if a log file size is bigger that the last time, if is not it means that the process had stopped or hanged sometime ago, in that case we need to search for the process id, if it exist kill it and restart it if not start it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer to your specific issue, it does not deal with the other problems with your code, *see my comment*, or take account of whether, once fixed, the overall task does as you intend it to.

As well as the problematic [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) line ending issue, *also implied in the comments*, you need to take account of the fact that when you run the `WMIC` command, you're doing so with the string `winlog` included. That means the `wmic.exe` process `CommandLine` will match the string `winlog` too and you'll need to filter against this. It gets more complicated though because the parenthesised `WMIC` command to `For` is also run in a separate instance of `cmd.exe` so the `cmd.exe` process `CommandLine` will contain the `WMIC` command and therefore the string `winlog` too. You would therefore need to additionally filter against this in your `WMIC` command as well.

In summary, of the three `ProcessID` outputs you've shown in your question, `8260`,`11576` and `8596` one is for the `winlogon` process, one the `cmd.exe` process and the other for the `wmic.exe` process.

I'd therefore suggest you change your specifically indicated problematic line to:

```bat
For /F EOL^=P %%A In ('WMIC Process Where "Name<>'cmd.exe' And Name<>'wmic.exe' And CommandLine Like '%%winlog%%'" Get ProcessID 2^>Nul')Do For %%B In (%%A)Do Set "commie=%%B"
```

I generally prefer to use `!=`, or this format, `Not Name=`, but as you've enabled delayed expansion, I decided to steer clear of exclamation points chose the shorter `<>` alternative.

*Please note that this answer cannot be expected to isolate a specific instance of `CommandLine` should there be more than one matching process. It also does not account for the possibility that your target `CommandLine` containing the string `winlog` could have been run through another instance of `cmd.exe`. If either of those two are possibilities, then your entire methodology needs a rethink.*

Comment: you were right, the "random numbers" were the cmd processes.After checking with echo on, i realized that the variable changed between the useful value and the cmd and wmic ones.

Comment: luckily i know the process name of the process I'm searching for, so I'm going to use that to filter between the process